# How to align text with ICON using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, themes

I want to align the second-row text with the first-line text.
Here's the URL of my website: `https://stgbusiness.wpengine.com/`

and here's the code:

```
<img src="https://stgbusiness.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/modules-icon.png" /><span class="m-icons">Contracts, Business Valuation and Pricing Negotiations</span>
```

[image]

is there a way I can make this text-align?

Comment: [Something on my site doesn't work, can I just post a link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I suggest you to add each line (img + span) on another div, and try to change display. Also, I think you can do a [mre] with code snippet to make it easier to us to show you code/to edit code

Answer (score 1):

I think ou can use flexbox and do it like that :

```css
.note {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
<img src="https://stgbusiness.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/modules-icon.png" />
<span>
Learn from the best in the business. Our Broker advisory board has a combined 150 years worth of business brokering experience
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: its sperating from the icon check image
https://i.imgur.com/L9nVDnQ.jpg

Comment: Have you added the CSS ?

Comment: yes, I already added the css